# WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(ServletContext) returns NULL from ServletContextListener

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-java-config

I am unable to get WebApplicationContext inside ServletContextListener. I searched for solution but non of them are working for me. I would appreciate if any one can help. Thanks in advance.

Below are code snippets-
My AppConfig class:

```
package in.andonsystem.config;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"in.andonsystem"})
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

   @Bean
   public ViewResolver viewResolver(){
      InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
      viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
      viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
      viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
      return viewResolver;
   }

   @Bean
   public MessageSource messageSource(){
      ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
      messageSource.setBasename("messages");     
      return messageSource;
   }

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
   }
}
```

My AppInitializer Class.

```
package in.andonsystem.config;

import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class Appinitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
      rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
      servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
      rootContext.refresh();

      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
              servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");

   }
}
```

My ContextListener Class:

```
package in.andonsystem.config;

import com.mysql.jdbc.AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread;
import java.sql.Driver;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils;

@WebListener
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

   private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ContextListener");


   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
      logger.info("contextInitialized()");

      WebApplicationContext rootContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext());
      System.out.println("Is rootContext null:" + (rootContext == null));

   }

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {

   }

}
```

stdout output is always coming true.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally came up with the solution. The problem was that ServletContextListener was being loaded before ContextLoaderListener and Therefore a WebApplicationContext returned was null because ContextLoaderListener must be loaded before ServletContextListener in order to get the rootContext.

I removed @WebListener annotation from my ContextListener and added this Listener Programatically in onStartup method of AppInitializer after Adding ContextLoaderListener.

Now my ContextListener without @WebListener annotation is:

```
public class ContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

   private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("ContextListener");


   @Override
   public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
      logger.info("contextInitialized()");

      WebApplicationContext rootContext = 
              WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sce.getServletContext());
      System.out.println("Is rootContext null:" + (rootContext == null));

   }

   @Override
   public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
      logger.info("contextDestroyed()");
   }

}
```

and AppInitializer is :

```
public class Appinitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer{

   @Override
   public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
      AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
      rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
      rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);

      // Manage the lifecycle of the root application context
      servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
      //ContextListener must be added after ContextLoaderListener
      servletContext.addListener(ContextListener.class);


      // Register and map the dispatcher servlet
      ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher =
              servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(rootContext));
      dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
      dispatcher.addMapping("/");

   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks basically correct, but I think you should remove the following 2 lines from your initializer class:

```
rootContext.setServletContext(servletContext);
```

and

```
rootContext.refresh();
```